# Buscar resultado em tabelas relacionadas

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, tenho um sistema de tickets para criar chamados e preciso fazer uma busca para trazer os chamados em aberto ordenados por ordem de prioridade, até ai tudo certo, preciso agora que o campo "$row->created_by" busque o nome do solicitante que está em outra tabela, atualmente ele trás o ID, eu tenho que usar Inner Join para fazer isso?

Alguém poderia me explicar a melhor forma de se fazer isso?

Agradecimentos antecipados.

```
  // Busca dados no banco
                    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT chamadosti.*,users.first_name FROM chamadosti INNER JOIN users ON users.id = chamadosti.created_by WHERE status='open' ORDER BY priority DESC "))
                    {
                            // exibir os registros se hÃ¡ registros para mostrar
                            if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                            {
                                    // exibir registros em uma tabela
                                    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing=0 style=border-collapse: collapse bordercolor='#4B5AAB'>";


                                    // definir cabeÃ§alhos de tabela
                                   echo "<tr> <th>N° do Chamado</th> <th>Prioridade</th> <th>Descrição</th> <th>Inicio</th> <th>Criado por:</th> <th>Assumiu:</th> <th>Categoria</th> <th>Sub chamado</th> <th>Editar</th> <th>Deletar</th></tr>";

                                    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                                    {
                                            // cria uma linha para cada registro
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode ($row->id) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode ($row->priority) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode ($row->summary) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode ($row->created_at) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode ($row->created_by) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode ($row->assigned_to) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode ($row->category) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . utf8_encode ($row->parent_id) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td><a href='edit_cam.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Editar</a></td>";
                                            echo "<td><a href='del_cam.php?id=" . $row->id . "' onclick=\"return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja deletar esse registro?');\">Deletar</a></td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                    }

                                    echo "</table>";
                            }
                            // se nÃ£o hÃ¡ registros no banco de dados, exibir uma mensagem de alerta
                            else
                            {
                                    echo "Nenhum registro encontrado!";
                            }
                    }
                    // mostrar um erro se houver um problema com a consulta de banco de dados
                    else
                    {
                            echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
                    }

                    // fecha con com banco
                    $mysqli->close();

            ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thiago, você pode usar o seguinte SQL:

`SELECT cha.*, u.first_name FROM chamadosti as cha INNER JOIN users as u ON u.id = cha.created_by WHERE cha.status='open' ORDER BY cha.priority DESC`

Ele vai trazer todas as informações que você já usa, mais o first_name da sua tabela de usuários.

Agora no seu arquivo, você pode utilizar o seguinte código onde desejar para exibir o nome resultante da sql:

`utf8_encode ($row->first_name)`

---

**EDIT**

Atendendo a nova solicitação, Thiago informou que os chamados agora possuem um responsável, que também é ligado a tabela `users` pelo campo `assigned_to` da tabela `chamadosti`, fazendo as alterações necessárias o SQL ficaria o seguinte:

```
SELECT cha.*, u_created.first_name as criador, u_assigned.first_name as responsavel FROM chamadosti as cha 
LEFT JOIN users as u_created ON u_created.id = cha.created_by 
LEFT JOIN users as u_assigned ON u_assigned.id = cha.assigned_to  
WHERE cha.status='open' ORDER BY cha.priority DESC
```

e agora para mostrar o criador e responsável você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
utf8_encode ($row->criador) // para mostrar o criador (vide: alias SQL)
utf8_encode ($row->responsavel) // para mostrar quem assumiu o chamado (vide: alias SQL)
```

Comment: Rafael, surgiu outra dúvida, preciso completar outro campo com nome de quem assumiu o chamado, como isso deve ser feito?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor como isso é feito @Thiago? Essa pessoa que assumiu o chamado, também é cadastrado na tabela users? O que liga esse usuário a tabela users? É um id na tabela chamadosti ? Você precisa alterar o SQL acima para que também traga essa pessoa que assumiu?

Comment: Sim, também está na mesma tabela users, exatamente a mesma coisa, o campo que eu quero que venha com o nome agora é "assigned_to", sim preciso que alem do nome de quem criou venha o nome de quem assumiu.

Comment: @Thiago pode tentar esse SQL: `SELECT cha.*, u_created.first_name, u_assigned.first_name FROM chamadosti as cha 
LEFT JOIN users as u_created ON u_created.id = cha.created_by 
LEFT JOIN users as u_assigned ON u_assigned.id = cha.assigned_to
WHERE cha.status='open' ORDER BY cha.priority DESC`

Comment: funcionou parcialmente, ele está chamando apenas os nomes de quem assumiu o chamado, os chamados que não foram assumidos por ninguém não vem com os nomes de quem criou o chamado.

Comment: @Thiago tenta esse aqui: `SELECT cha.*, u_created.first_name as criador, u_assigned.first_name as responsavel FROM chamadosti as cha 
LEFT JOIN users as u_created ON u_created.id = cha.created_by
LEFT JOIN users as u_assigned ON u_assigned.id = cha.assigned_to 
WHERE cha.status='open' ORDER BY cha.priority DESC`

Comment: Não trás nenhum resultado, eu devo usar utf8_encode ($row->first_name) mesmo?

Comment: Ah sim desculpe, esqueci de comentar, coloquei alias nos dois campos para não ter mais o problema de antes... use `utf8_encode ($row->criador)` e `utf8_encode ($row->responsavel)`

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou perfeitamente, desculpe meu descuido de não notar ali que você nomeou como criador e  responsavel, Muito agradecido ;)

Comment: @Thiago ótimo :), vou alterar a resposta para adicionar essa nova situação.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Tente usar este código:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela INNER JOIN tabela_usuario ON tabela_usuario.id = tabela.created_by 
WHERE tabela.status='open'  
ORDER BY tabela.priority DESC
```

Comment: Eu preciso que somente o campo "created_by" venha com resultado "first_name" da tabela de usuarios.